# What format do I need to publish a ROS message geometry/Point32

Tags: javascript, websocket, ros

I have a JavaScript web application publishing/subscribing to ROS using rosbridge_suite/web sockets.

I can successfully publish/subscribe to topics with std_msgs/String, std_msgs/Int32, etc, so I know that my connection is fine. What I'm having issues with is knowing how to format data to be published to a topic that accepts geometry/Point32.

Here's an example:

```
const topic = new ROSLIB.Topic({
  ros, // defined elsewhere
  name: '/my_topic',
  messageType: 'geometry_msgs/Point32'
});


topic.publish({ data: { x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0 } });
```

Then, I run `rostopic echo /my_topic` but I can't get it to show up. Again, all my other topics work and they're structured the same way. My coworkers and I ended up changing he messageType to a string and parsing out the values, but I really think this should be possible. Any ideas?

**Here's what I've tried:**

```
publish({ data: { x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0 } })
publish({ x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0 })
publish(JSON.stringify({ x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0 } }))
publish({ data: JSON.stringify({ x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0 } }) })
publish({ data: 'x: 1.0, y: 1.0' })

const coords = ROSLIB.Message({
  x: 1.0,
  y: 1.0,
  z: 1.0
});

publish({ data: coords });
publish(coords);
```

...

You get the idea.

I'm using ROS Kinetic.

Answer (score 1):

[Point32](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Point32.html) is composed as follows:

```
float32 x
float32 y
float32 z
```

The [BasicRosFunctionality tutorial of roslibjs](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs/Tutorials/BasicRosFunctionality) describes how to define messages to publish:

> It takes in an object literal that matches up to the message definition on the ROS system. Nested objects are fine.

This means you need to **create an object exactly matching the message definition**. Since there is no field called `data` in the message, your example

```
topic.publish({ data: { x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0 } });
```

simply does not match and will not work. To get your code to run just remove the `data` field to match the message definition:

```
topic.publish({ x: 0.1, y: 0.2, z: 0.3 });
```

Comment: I would expect this to work as well, however, OP already tried it (second line in the "Here's what I've tried" block).

Comment: OP was already close to the solution, unfortunately there is a bracket `}` too much at the second statement he tried.

Comment: Thanks @Fruchtzwerg I do have a lot of linting set up, so my project would have warned me on that probably, but I'll try again. I probably just typed it in here incorrectly.

Comment: The code I've posted should do the trick, in my case the message was published like expected.

Comment: Was the problem solved by fixing the brackets @kauffee000 ?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg unfortunately, no. We ended up switching the data type to Std_msgs/String because we had a demo the next day and it needed to work.